# How to unit test a function that creates a connection object assuming there will not be internet access?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python function that creates a Client object from the aiosnow module, which is an API wrapper for ServiceNow like this:

```
from aiosnow import Client


def create_snow_client(url: str, user_name: str, pwd: str) -> Client:
    """Creates ServiceNow client object for interacting with the API."""

    client = Client(
        url,
        basic_auth=(user_name, pwd),
    )

    return client
```

Assuming I will not have internet connection during unit testing, how or what part am I supposed to make the unit test for, which part am I supposed to mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is just to guarantee that the `Client` constructor has been called. You can accomplish this with [`unittest.mock.Mock().assert_called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) (or some variant of it, like `assert_called_with`). This will entail mocking the `Client` class, so that when the test runs and you call the `Client` constructor, no code from `Client` actually runs. The mock gets called and then you can make assertions based on what you expected to happen.

This is a correct approach because you and your test don't care about the inner workings of the `Client` class. You're testing your function which is supposed to create a client, *not* that `Client` works correctly. By mocking out the `Client` class, your test simply guarantees that your code instantiated a `Client`, but doesn't run any `Client` code.

Here's an example:

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        print("New Foo!")


def use_foo():
    print(f"foo: {Foo()}")


@patch("__main__.Foo")
def test_foo(mocked_foo):
    use_foo()
    print(f"Mocked Foo called? {mocked_foo.called}")


def main():
    print("Using foo\n")
    use_foo()

    print("\nTesting foo\n")
    test_foo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and here's the corresponding output:

```
Using foo

New Foo!
foo: <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fdfcaba2ac0>

Testing foo

foo: <MagicMock name='Foo()' id='140599155357056'>
Mocked Foo called? True
```

You can see that `"New Foo"` did not appear in the output of the test, because the class has been mocked.

You can read more about mocking in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).